# jquery reloads the page when button is clicked

Tags: jquery, laravel-5

I've a `get` route, that returns a view with data, the view has a form (I'm using  LaravelColletive's html package), that form has a button **that's not** the submit one, this button has a click event triggered by jQuery, what it does is that it appends some elements to the view.

The problem I'm having is that when I click on the button it reloads the page, the action is made, but because of the reload the page form has no value again.

Here's the jquery action

```
    $("#completarseleccion").click(function(){
    var btn_element = $(this);
    //this is how you loop through your item and add it to a specific element
    $(".opcion").each(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("clicked")){
            $($(this).html()).append('#menuseleccionado');
        }
    });
});
```

Actually if the button has no action, if I click it, it reloads the page...

My application is under laravel 5.0
How could I solve that?

Comment: Please add some code. Its nearly impossible, to imagine where the problem is, when no sample is given.

Comment: The button is inside a form?

Comment: You can try use event.preventDefault() too...

Comment: Yes, the button is inside a form @dzanella

Comment: I'll try out @aspirin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm taking a guess here - Your submit button is inside the `form` tag. In this case you have options:

1. Close the `<form>` tag before the button
2. If that can be done, either `return false` from the click event
   handler or use the event object to say `e.preventDefault();`

However, in case 2 if you wish to submit the form at a later stage, you'll have to do it programmatically by calling the `.submit()` function on the form object.

Answer (score 0):

Add `event` to the click function arguments, and then at the top of the callback function use `event.preventDefault();`

```
$("#completarseleccion").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var btn_element = $(this);
    //this is how you loop through your item and add it to a specific element
    $(".opcion").each(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("clicked")){
            $($(this).html()).append('#menuseleccionado');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#completarseleccion").click(function(e){ 
  e.preventDefault(); 
  var btn_element = $(this); 
   //this is how you loop through your item and add it to a specific element 
  $(".opcion").each(function()
  {
 if($(this).hasClass("clicked"))
$($(this).html()).append('#menuseleccionado'); } }); });
```

Comment: Doesnt work, if i add that line it doesn't do anything